# Unable to convertjupyter notebook to pdf

Tags: windows

I am getting an error `nbconvert failed: xelatex not found on PATH, if you have not installed xelatex you may need to do so. Find further instructions at https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-tex.`

Now before I was getting error for not having pandoc so i installed pandoc msi file. I use jupyter notebook in windows 10.
I am unable to convert jupyter notebook into pdf

Now before I was getting error for not having pandoc so i installed pandoc msi file. I use jupyter notebook in windows 10.
I am unable to convert jupyter notebook into pdf